# Decoding on NSynth is wretchedly slow for me

Tags: tensorflow, magenta

I just recently got turned onto this project and I'm really excited about it. So thanks for all the hard work.

Im using:
2012 Macbook Pro
running High Sierra
2.6 Ghz Intel Core i7
Nvidia GForce Gt 650M 1Gb
16 gb of memory

My first idea was to use my own samples to encode + decode. I followed along with the Jupyter notebook example and wrote a little python script to process a short wav file - we're talking 2 or 3 seconds long. Encoding is done with ease but I have yet to successfully decode because it is just taking too long. I left it on overnight and almost 7 hours later the thing was still running. Tried with a few different files with the same results.

The only clue I'm running on right now is this error:
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.2 AVX

Apparently, compiling from source for my specific architecture could be a way to speed things up - but my feeling is it is just wretchedly slow right now

Is my computer simply doomed to this kind of performance? Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need to just reinstall w/optimization for my machine?

For clarity, my code is below.
Please and thank you.

---

import os

import numpy as np

from magenta.models.nsynth import utils

from magenta.models.nsynth.wavenet import fastgen

fname = 'aggression.wav'

sr = 16000

audio = utils.load_audio(fname, sample_length=40000, sr=sr)

sample_length = audio.shape[0]

print('{} samples, {} seconds'.format(sample_length, sample_length / float(sr)))

encoding = fastgen.encode(audio, os.path.abspath('model.ckpt-200000'), sample_length)

print(encoding.shape)

np.save(fname + '.npy', encoding)

fastgen.synthesize(encoding, save_paths=['gen_' + fname], samples_per_save=sample_length)

sr = 16000

synthesis = utils.load_audio('gen_' + fname, sample_length=sample_length, sr=sr)

print('Magenta Test')

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the wavenet autoencoder is very compute intensive and you need a high-end GPU to make it work fast. Luckily Google provides a free one for you along with Colab. This notebook (https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/magenta/nsynth/nsynth.ipynb) has an example of synthesizing with NSynth.